# I am trying create a bsc token but keeps getting this error

Tags: solidity

```
function functionCallWithValue(
    address target,
    bytes memory data,
    uint256 value,
    string memory errorMessage
) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        require(address(this).balance >= value, "Address: insufficient balance" for call");
        return _functionCallWithValue(target, data, value, errorMessage);
}
```

i keep getting

```
ParserError: Expected ',' but got 'for' for call"); ^-^
```

Comment: I formatted your code for easier readability but kept the original error.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error (possibly caused by a typo) in this statement:

```
require(address(this).balance >= value, "Address: insufficient balance" for call");
```

The second argument needs to be a string literal (wrapped in quotes `"` or apostrophes `'`) or a string variable.

Your string argument starts with a quote sign `"`, but then you have another quote sign right after the `balance` word, which suggests the string ends here. But in fact, it shouldn't end here, and the compiler is not able to recognize the rest of the literal.

---

**Solution**: Remove the redundant quote sign (from after the `balance` word).

```
require(address(this).balance >= value, "Address: insufficient balance for call");
```